# Same net overlapping pads ok?

Tags: pcb-design, clearance

I'd like to keep the option between components with slightly different footprints. In this particular case it's tactile switches with either 6.5mm or 8mm distance between legs. It looks ok to me but I'm not sure if there are any contradictions. Are there?

[image]

Update, yeah it works.
[image]

Comment: If those are through-hole, then the trace to the left is probably too close to the lower left pads. You probably want to route it up through the centre instead. PTH pads are normally the same size front and rear.

Comment: the center of the switch is different for the two sizes ... that may make a difference if the actuator passes through a hole in the enclosire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally fine as long as you obey the manufacturer's minimum hole-to-hole spacing rule. The Design Rule Check (DRC) of your PCB software will tell you whether you've violated those rules anywhere. Note that for this to work, you'll of course have to look up the manufacturer's design rules first and enter them into the software. In the KiCAD PCB editor, which you appear to be using, you can do this with the PCB configuration button in the top left corner of the window:

[image: PCB config button]

If DRC passes with the correct ruleset, you're pretty much good to go.

As mentioned in a comment under your question, the leftmost red trace might be a little unhappy being so close to the through-hole pad. (Unless it's on an inner layer.)

Comment: Ah nice, didn't discover those settings yet. DRC is fine with a hole-to-hole value of 0.25mm (KiCad preset & JLCPCB "Via to Via clearance(Same nets)") but fails with a setting of 0.5mm (JLCPCB "Hole to hole clearance(Different nets)"). Guess that will work :)